# SQL Server 2012: Return unlisted records from a two table compare, grouped by categories

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hypothetical scenario to explain my problem query: I have four customers that all bought different types of animals at my store (`CustomerData` table). A report was pulled across all my stores in the nation of their ranked top-selling animals, by animal name and breed (`TopAnimals` table). I want to know which animals each of my customers are not buying.

In my experience, the following should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CustomerData
FULL OUTER JOIN TopAnimals ON CustomerData.Animal = TopAnimals.Animal
WHERE CustomerData.Animal IS NULL --Since I want to see the animals my customers DIDN'T buy, per customer
```

But instead, this is returning only the items that are on both tables, which is not the desired result.

Here is the data behind my query:

**CustomerData** (what they bought)

```
Customer    Animal      Breed
-------------------------------------
A           bird        Heron
A           cat         Siamese
A           cat         Persian
A           dog         Husky
B           cat         Maine Coon
B           fish        Bass
C           bird        Bald Eagle
C           bird        Pigeon
C           cat         Ragdoll
C           dog         Corgi
C           dog         Golden Retriever
C           fish        Carp
C           fish        Catfish
D           bird        Heron
D           bird        Vulture
D           cat         Maine Coon
D           cat         Persian
D           dog         Corgi
D           dog         German Shepherd
D           dog         Golden Retriever
```

**TopAnimals** (what everyone else bought; most popular)

```
Rank#   Animal  Breed
-----------------------------
1       bird    Bald eagle
2       bird    Heron
3       bird    Vulture
4       bird    Pigeon
1       cat     Siamese
2       cat     Persian
3       cat     Maine Coon
4       cat     Ragdoll
1       dog     Golden Retriever
2       dog     German Shepherd
3       dog     Corgi
4       dog     Husky
1       fish    Bluegill
2       fish    Bass
3       fish    Carp
4       fish    Catfish
```

**ResultData** (what customers didn't buy compared to popular animals report)

```
Customer    Animal  Breed
---------------------------------
A           bird    Bald eagle
A           bird    Pigeon
A           bird    Vulture
A           cat     Maine Coon
A           cat     Ragdoll
A           dog     Corgi
A           dog     German Shepherd
A           dog     Golden Retriever
A           fish    Bass
A           fish    Bluegill
A           fish    Carp
A           fish    Catfish
B           bird    Bald eagle
B           bird    Heron
B           bird    Pigeon
B           bird    Vulture
B           cat     Persian
B           cat     Ragdoll
B           cat     Siamese
B           dog     Corgi
B           dog     German Shepherd
B           dog     Golden Retriever
B           dog     Husky
B           fish    Bluegill
B           fish    Carp
B           fish    Catfish
C           bird    Heron
C           bird    Vulture
C           cat     Maine Coon
C           cat     Persian
C           cat     Siamese
C           dog     German Shepherd
C           dog     Husky
C           fish    Bass
C           fish    Bluegill
D           bird    Bald eagle
D           bird    Pigeon
D           cat     Ragdoll
D           cat     Siamese
D           dog     Husky
D           fish    Bass
D           fish    Bluegill
D           fish    Carp
D           fish    Catfish
```

If you guys can help me fix my query to obtain the **ResultData** table please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can also use the set operation EXCEPT as below:

```
select distinct(c.Customer), t.Animal, t.Breed
from CustomerData c
cross join TopAnimals t
EXCEPT
select Customer, Animal, Breed
from CustomerData
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then eliminate the ones that exist.  Here is one way:

```
select c.customerid, ta.animal, ta.breed
from (select distinct customerid from customerdata) c left join
     topanimals ta left join
     customerdata cd
     on cd.breed = ta.breed and cd.animal = ta.animal
where ta.breed is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TopAnimals 
LEFT Join CustomerData 
 on TopAnimals.Animal = CustomerData.Animal AND TopAnimals.Breed = CustomerData.Breed
Where CustomerData.Animal IS NULL
```

maybe like that?